# I can not deploy a argo-ui on k8s

Tags: kubernetes, argo-workflows

i use this yaml start a argo-server and argo-ui ,but argo-ui can not work ,how i do that?

this yaml is Official ,i just change the image version, argo-server and workflow-controller fine ,but argo-ui deployment status is FailedCreate

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/argoproj/argo/v2.2.1/manifests/install.yaml
```

result

[image]

Comment: Hi, Welcome on stack! We avoid here placing outputs, erorr, logs as picture so if you could be so kind and update those in the question that would be great! Also if possible can you please update your question with output from `kubectl describe deployment argo-ui` ?

Comment: 2.2.1 is pretty old. Besides adding the info thomas suggested, you might want to upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

argo-ui is no longer used nor part of the official manifests. It has superseded by argo-server, which serves the UI. You can delete it and access argo-server instead.

Comment: thanks , Perfectly solved my problem , argo-server ui can do work